# How to change my username?

Tags: support

How can I change my *username*? I tried a lot but not found any option to change it. Please can you elaborate that is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange doesn't use usernames, but display names, which you can change on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/edit/45681: Go to your profile page and click on the *Edit Profile & Settings* tab; near your picture, you will find the *Display name* text-field.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm not talking about **Display name** rather I asking about **username**,

Comment: As you can look at the url `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/45681/waqar-ali` ,

Comment: @WaQaRAli The slug in this url (`waqar-ali`) is automatically generated from your display name.

Comment: @WaQaRAli Stack Exchange doesn't use usernames. If you are referring to the username you use to log in, SE uses emails to log in.

Comment: ok,  I got your point :)